# How can I create a multi-colum dropdown menu in Materialize CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I'm working on a personal project and due to a high number of elements for the drop down menu, a multi column (2 columns, to be precise) would work better. How do I go about accomplishing this in Materialize CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Is this similar to what you have in mind? It takes a bit of custom CSS to remove some padding that makes the list items look odd, but it shows two drop columns, and snaps to one on smaller devices.

HTML

```
<div id="dropdown1" class="row dropdown-content">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <ul>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#dropdown1 div {
  padding: 0;
}

#dropdown1 li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0c588g8/)